# Even and odd subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $a_n$ be a sequence. Assume that $b_n$ and $c_n$ are the odd and even subsequences of $a_n$, respectively. How we can define odd and even subsequences of $b_n$ and $c_n$? I think if $n\equiv 1\pmod 4$ and $n\equiv 3\pmod 4$, then we have odd and even subsequences of  $b_n$, respectively. By similar argument, If $n\equiv 0\pmod 4$ and $n\equiv 2\pmod 4$, then we have even and odd subsequences of  $c_n$, respectively.

**Questions:**

1. Is the above correct?
2. If i prove the odd and even subsequences of $b_n$ are convergent to the same limit, then $b_n$ is convergent?  (Like when the odd and even subsequences of a sequence are convergent to the same limit then the sequence is convergent.)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: For the last question, no, consider $(-1)^n$.

Comment: @player3236, Thank you. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Consider the sequence $a_n = n$.

Then $(b_n)=1,3,5,7,9,\dots$ and $(c_n) = 2,4,6,8,10,\dots$.

The odd subsequence of $c_n$ is therefore actually $2, 6, 10,\dots$ which is $n\equiv 2\pmod 4$.

---

2. Yes. Any two complementary subsequences converging to the same limit implies the convergence to the same limit of the original sequence:

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Suppose both $b_{2n+1}$ and $b_{2n}$ converges to $L$. Then:

$$\exists M\in\mathbb N: \forall 2n+1>M:|b_{2n+1}-L|<\epsilon$$
$$\exists N\in\mathbb N: \forall 2n>N:|b_{2n}-L|<\epsilon$$

Hence for all $n>\max\{M,N\}$, $|b_n - L|<\epsilon$, which proves that $b_n$ converges to $L$.